# Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error: How to find which source file caused error?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, javac

I know there has been several other questions where someone had a problem because they got a similair error compiling, but it isn't quite the same error. In their case the problem seemed to be that Maven didn't have the path to the correct compiler. In my case the problem appears to be that there is an incorrectly written class/type somewhere.

Result when compling:

```
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_20). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ErrorType cannot be cast to com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ArrayType
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr$TypeAnnotationsValidator.validateAnnotatedType(Attr.java:4637)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr$TypeAnnotationsValidator.visitMethodDef(Attr.java:4485)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:778)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr$TypeAnnotationsValidator.visitClassDef(Attr.java:4552)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:693)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.validateTypeAnnotations(Attr.java:4451)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$2.run(TypeAnnotations.java:142)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:155)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:512)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:471)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:982)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:857)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:381)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:370)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:361)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess(JavacCompiler.java:554)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compile(JavacCompiler.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:605)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

ErrorType (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/ErrorType.html) means that some kind of class or Interface etc isn't written correctly and can't be modelled.

ArrayType just means it was an array. So most likely this means that somewhere I am using an incomplete/missing class as an array.

Also this was in visitMethodDef() -> validateAnnotatedType() meaning that perhaps this is the return type/parameter for a method?

What could be causing this? Why doesn't the compiler say where in the source code this happend?

Im using Maven 2.4 and JDK 1.8. I normally don't have any problems with compiling.

Here is a snippet of my maven pom.xml file:

```
 <build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
              <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
              <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>PATH.TO.MAIN.CLASS</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>  
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                <include>**/*.css</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.png</include>
                <include>**/*.gif</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

I also tried compiling with more output from Maven but I didn't see anything usefull for detecting the error.

Why doesn't the compiler show in which file the incomplete type is? How can I compile in such a way as to show what file had the error? Is it possible to validate an individual file to find such an error?

A simillair error has had a bug report here(https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwix2evZmt3cAhXoNJoKHWQ7BXAQFjABegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnetbeans.org%2Fbugzilla%2Fshow_bug.cgi%3Fid%3D247421&usg=AOvVaw3ulnafW3ET1VWqw43wAEC0) where someone tried to combine Lists/arrays but had incorrect syntax. But is there a way too find out which file contains the error?

Comment: This is the most important line of that StackTrace: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ErrorType cannot be cast to com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ArrayType
 For one, it explains what goes wrong, secondly: google that line, and you'll get tons of links discussing it. Most likely a solution to your problem is already explained in detail online

Comment: But how can I compile in such a way so that it will show the offending file? ErrorType means that the source file isn't wrriten correctly so that the class isn't complete. ArrayType simply means that it is an array. I will edit my answer with a link to someone who had a similair bug.

Comment: actually, just follow the stacktrace. The 'offending file' as you say, should be in there.

Comment: Well the stacktrace/error message should contain more info about what file it was. But it doesn't. This is when compiling the project and the entire stack trace is the Java compiler with no info about what it was caused by. In my edited answer there is a bug report where someone had the same ClassCastException but that included information about which file it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem was.

I had a method declaration:

```
public synchronized static T[] <T> foo(...)
```

Instead of

```
public synchronized static <T> T[] foo(...)
```

Unbelivably frustrating that the compiler doesn't even say which source file it was.